# C pointer arithmetic while subtracting

Tags: c

```
int a[ ] ={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19};
    int *pa = &a[4],*pb = &a[1];
```

What is the value of `pa-pb`? Ans: 3, but how? Shouldn't it be 12 (like I printed `pa` and `pb` too, to double check, and got 12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is very different from normal arithmetic. In pointer arithmetic `a-1`, where `a` is pointer doesn't mean value of `a` subtracted with 1. it means go back by one unit of memory.

In your example, `pa-pb` doesn't mean value of `pa-pb`. one int variable requires 4 bytes so `pa-pb` means go back by three int's to reach `pb` from `pa`.

For `int` one unit of memory is 4 bytes, float 8 bytes, char 1 byte. 
**NOTE:** *These value changes from system to system, its usually these value.*